# Openlink Virtuoso does not apply FILTER using SERVICE clause

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, virtuoso, fuseki, d2rq

I am trying to run the following query both from Virtuoso and Fuseki-server. I use the `SERVICE` clause to connect to the SPARQL endpoint of D2R.
The problem is that while Fuseki correctly applies the `FILTER`, Virtuoso doesn't do the same and returns the entire unfiltered result set.

I use Virtuoso version number `07.20.3214` for Windows, Fuseki-server version `2` and D2RQ version `0.8.1`.

The query is the following

```
SELECT ?line ?state ?arrivalTime ?idRide
WHERE 
{
    {  
    SELECT ?ride (MAX(?avmr) AS ?avmrLast)
    WHERE
    {
    ?bs rdf:type km4c:BusStop.
    ?bs foaf:name "COLONNA".
    SERVICE <http://localhost:2020/sparql>
    {     
        ?bsf km4c:isForecastOfBusStop ?bs.
        ?bsf km4c:isForecastOfAVM ?avmr.
        ?ride km4c:hasAVMRecord ?avmr.
    }       
    }
GROUP BY ?ride ORDER BY DESC (?avmrLast) LIMIT 15
}

?bs rdf:type km4c:BusStop.
?bs foaf:name "COLONNA". 
SERVICE <http://localhost:2020/sparql>
{ 
    ?forecast km4c:isForecastOfBusStop ?bs .
    ?forecast km4c:isForecastOfAVM ?avmrLast .
    ?forecast km4c:expectedTime ?arrivalTime.
    ?avmrLast km4c:concernLine ?line.
    ?avmrLast km4c:rideState ?state.
    ?ride dcterms:identifier ?idRide.
}  
FILTER(?arrivalTime> "2015-01-01T09:00:00+02:00")
} ORDER BY ?arrivalTime
```

The point is that `FILTER` is not applied. With Virtuoso, I get results whose `?arrivalTime <= 2015-01-01T09:00:00+02:00`, while Fuseki works fine.

If I run a "normal" query, without `SERVICE` for instance, `FILTER` works fine in Virtuoso too.

Which may be the reasons?

Comment: FYI FILTER(?arrivalTime> "2015-01-01T09:00:00+02:00") is a test of ?arrivalTime and a string.  Add ^^xsd;dateTime.

Comment: What are the datatypes of values of ?arrivalTime on remote and on your boxes?